# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'spdx-exceptions'

Tags: elasticsearch, npm, kibana, npm-publish, eui

I get this error while executing a script for building kibana version 7.9.1. That build usually runs smoothly. The new thing in my case is that I replaced dependencies like @elastic/eui with a customized @elastic/eui npm package published on my gitlab package registry. Application runs without any problem when launched in dev mode with yarn start. The error arises in the course of the build of the docker images.

More logs here:

```
Built at: 10/07/2021 3:56:20 PM
   Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  2.21 MiB       0  [emitted]  index
Entrypoint index = index.js
  [0] ./src/index.ts 1.09 KiB {0} [built]
  [1] ./src/cli.ts 3.5 KiB {0} [built]
  [4] external "path" 42 bytes {0} [built]
  [5] ../kbn-dev-utils/target/tooling_log/index.js 1.79 KiB {0} [built]
[112] external "util" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[127] ./src/commands/index.ts 1.06 KiB {0} [built]
[130] ./src/utils/fs.ts 3.02 KiB {0} [built]
[133] external "fs" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[143] ./src/utils/log.ts 1.54 KiB {0} [built]
[145] ./src/utils/projects.ts 6.3 KiB {0} [built]
[162] ./src/utils/errors.ts 921 bytes {0} [built]
[163] ./src/utils/project.ts 8.26 KiB {0} [built]
[266] ./src/utils/workspaces.ts 2.82 KiB {0} [built]
[267] ./src/config.ts 2.54 KiB {0} [built]
[480] ./src/production/index.ts 954 bytes {0} [built]
    + 687 hidden modules

ERROR in /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'spdx-exceptions' in '/mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse'
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js 6:17-43
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/index.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/index.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/read-pkg/index.js
 @ ./src/utils/package_json.ts
 @ ./src/utils/workspaces.ts
 @ ./src/index.ts

ERROR in /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-correct/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'spdx-license-ids' in '/mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-correct'
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-correct/index.js 17:21-48
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/index.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/read-pkg/index.js
 @ ./src/utils/package_json.ts
 @ ./src/utils/workspaces.ts
 @ ./src/index.ts

ERROR in /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'spdx-license-ids' in '/mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse'
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js 4:10-37
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/index.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/index.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/read-pkg/index.js
 @ ./src/utils/package_json.ts
 @ ./src/utils/workspaces.ts
 @ ./src/index.ts

ERROR in /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'spdx-license-ids/deprecated' in '/mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse'
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js 5:10-48
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse/index.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/index.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js
 @ /mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/node_modules/read-pkg/index.js
 @ ./src/utils/package_json.ts
 @ ./src/utils/workspaces.ts
 @ ./src/index.ts
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
   │ERROR failure 10 sec
   │ERROR Error: Command failed with exit code 2: yarn run build
   │          at makeError (/mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/packages/kbn-pm/dist/index.js:22616:11)
   │          at handlePromise (/mnt/ssd/projects/okp4bi/packages/kbn-pm/dist/index.js:21552:26)
   │          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```